# Asleap hacking tool and ubuntu wifi folder

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Disclaimer: I am working on my homework and my professor asked us to look at Asleap hacking tool.

Issue: As per the documentation http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/AsleapMain.htm

The author has asked to download latest code to /tools/wifi. I am able to locate the /tools under the ubuntu folder but unable to locate the /tools/wifi folder.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. I am taking baby steps with this and getting struck here and there.

Comment: can someone please help me with this question :(, I cannot even try to chat with some of you due to low rep points :(

Comment: Since `/tools` is a non-standard directory, if you found it, then it might be part of some larger package or something that you created. If you created it, create `wifi` as Jared says.

Comment: @muru I ended up creating a wifi folder when I try to make the file I get net/bpf.h not found. Should I post this as a new question please help me pass this hurdle.

Comment: New question would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just have to make the folder and extract it there. Try that and good luck!

```
cd /tools
mkdir wifi
cd wifi
```

Comment: I created a folder with name wifi